# What is the difference between axios.get(url) and window.location.assign(url)

Tags: get, axios, fetch, httprequest

Are there any headers that are different in both cases? Because both are making a GET request

Comment: I can see the difference of following headers:
With axios/fetch =>
sec-fetch-dest: empty,
sec-fetch-mode: cors.

And with window.location.assign =>
sec-fetch-dest: document,
sec-fetch-mode: navigate

Comment: I think these headers are prohibiting document to load while using axios/fetch and if I switch to window.location.assign document is loading fine. Can someone please help me here.

Comment: Can I set these headers explicitly using axios/fetch ?